# Using console to choose and change a global variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, global-variables

I'm learning python and trying to use a function to choose and change a global variable.

I want to use the console to choose which variable to change and then choose the new value.

I'm using `global` inside the function to access the variables and I'm using `exec()` to proceed with the desired modification captured through `input()`. But something is not working.

Can someone please figure out what is wrong here?

```py
name = "John"
age = 45
gender = "male"

def identify_yourself():
    print("My name is " + name + ".")
    print("I'm " + str(age) + " years old.")
    print("I'm " + gender + ".")
    
def change_something():
    global name, age, gender
    something = input("Which variable do you want to change?\n> ")
    
    # I then input "name"
    
    new_value = input("Change to what?\n> ")
    
    # I Then input "Paul"
    
    exec(something + " = '" + new_value + "'")
    identify_yourself()

identify_yourself()

# This first prints... 
# 
# My name is John.
# I'm 45 years old.
# I'm male.

change_something()

# On the second time this SHOULD print... 
# 
# My name is Paul.
# I'm 45 years old.
# I'm male.
# 
# ... but it's not working.
# It keeps printing "My name is John" even after I run the change_something() function
```

Comment: And a second on google gave me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083353/cannot-change-global-variables-in-a-function-through-an-exec-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec()` uses `globals()` and `locals()` as defaults for their global and local variables. It defaults to changes in the `locals()`, not the globals. You therefore have to explicitly tell it to overwrite globals. You can do this the following way:

```
exec(something + " = '" + new_value + "'", globals())
```

Comment: Thanks!

It didn't work first time, but when I deleted the `global` call in the first line of the function it went through.